# what's meaning of "beating me by 2 seconds"?

Tags: meaning

What is meaning of `beat me by 2 seconds`?

In this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1237610/my-mac-use-a-link-can-download-a-file-but-in-a-windows-server-it-did-not-downlo/1237614#1237614), there is a comment:

> +1 for beating me by 2 seconds

I am not understand the meaning, which friend can help me with that?

Comment: To *beat someone* in general: to do better than them. In this context specifically: To be faster than them. So "You were two seconds faster than me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full expression is [**to beat someone to something**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beat-someone-to-something). The meaning is very simple: to be faster in accomplishing something than somebody else.

> We were competing who would arrive at the university first and he **beat me to it by 5 minutes**. He arrived 5 minutes earlier at the university than I did.